# using two prepositions 'at' one after another

Tags: prepositions, style

For the following sentence:

> Jack and Jenny arrive at school at 3:00 pm.

If I wanted to ask a question about Jack and Jenny's particular place of arrival at specific point in time, which is 3:00 pm, would it be ok to form the question this way?:

> Where do Jack and Jenny arrive **at at** 3:00 pm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It'd be a *single* **'at'** because *Where* in your question takes care of the preposition used for the school.

> Where do Jack and Jenny arrive? ~ ***At*** school.

So, now you add the time's question with just a single *at.*

> Where do Jack and Jenny arrive ***at*** 3 pm?